# error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android, material-design

I am working on navigation drawer project ,I am trying material theme navigation drawer I found one example from github neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer,I imported this project after that I add appcompat library still i am getting this error from styles.
styles:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="NavigationDrawer" parent="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#8bc34a</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#558b2f</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/grey_1000</item>
</style>
<!-- Light version theme. -->
<style name="NavigationDrawer" parent="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#8bc34a</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#558b2f</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/grey_1000</item>
</style>
<!-- Light version with Black actionbar -->
<style name="NavigationDrawer" parent="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#8bc34a</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#558b2f</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/grey_1000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light.DarkActionBar` is part of the `it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer` package which should be found as soon as you add it to the dependencies of your `build.gradle` (app module) file like this (don't forget to sync after you changed it):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.2.9'
}
```

You should also choose just 1 of the 3 `NavigationDrawer` definitions in your `styles.xml` file.